# Creating process to run IE on new Windows desktop

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi, desktop

I'm trying to set up an IE kiosk which runs IE on a separate desktop. While I'm testing I'm just starting IE normally (not in kiosk mode), but although IE starts up on the new desktop it doesn't load the initial page specified in the command string, it just sits there with the hourglass flickering on and off really quickly (even when I move the mouse elsewhere on the desktop, outside the IE window). There is no URL displayed in the navigation box. I can access the menus and so on inside IE, but even if I type in a URL by hand nothing happens. Closing IE takes me back to the default desktop as expected.

A couple of extra things I tried: launching a command prompt (works fine, and I can ping the site I'm trying to connect to, so Internet access from the new desktop isn't blocked); launching Notepad with a filename parameter (works fine, opens the specified file, so I'm passing the command-line parameter correctly).

This is my code; any thoughts welcomed:

```
#include <windows.h>

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                   HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                   LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                   int       nCmdShow)
{
  char* desktop   = "MyDesktop";

  HDESK hThreadDT = GetThreadDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
  HDESK hInputDT  = OpenInputDesktop(0, FALSE, DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP);
  HDESK hNewDT    = CreateDesktop(desktop, NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);

  SetThreadDesktop(hNewDT);
  SwitchDesktop(hNewDT);

  if (SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\Internet Explorer")) {
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    STARTUPINFO si;

    memset(&pi, 0, sizeof(pi));
    memset(&si, 0, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    si.lpDesktop = desktop;

    if (CreateProcess(NULL, "iexplore.exe http://www.google.com",
                      NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)) {
      WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess,INFINITE);
    }
    else {
      char msg[1000];
      wsprintf(msg,"CreateProcess failed (%d)",GetLastError());
      MessageBox(NULL,msg,NULL,MB_OK);
    }
  }

  SwitchDesktop(hInputDT);
  SetThreadDesktop(hThreadDT);
  CloseDesktop(hNewDT);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something else I just tried: I started IE and also a copy of Process Explorer on the same desktop to get more information about what IE is doing. What I found is that C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe has one or two subprocesses running C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe, which seem to be continually failing, dying and being recreated. Manually running the (x86) version from the command line also gives me the same flickery cursor behaviour. So it seems to be something funny with IE. I'm going to try Chrome now and see what happens.

Comment: Hmm, it works perfectly with Chrome! So why is the 64-bit IE running 32-bit subprocesses, I wonder...?

Comment: It seems that this is down to IE tab isolation; disabling it by setting the appropriate registry key makes everything work fine. So it looks like what's happening is that the subprocesses for the tabs are being started on the default desktop rather than the current one, and promptly failing because the enclosing window isn't there. OTOH, IE works fine in any desktop with Sysinternals Desktops, so there must be a solution...

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the following command line to `CreateProcess` ([more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh826025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

`"iexplore.exe -k -noframemerging http://www.google.com"`

You also have an option to automate Internet Explorer via OLE [`InternetExplorer.Application`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object, particularity with `put_Visible`, `put_FullScreen` and `Navigate2` methods.

Comment: Nope, -noframemerging doesn't do it. And I don't see a way to use OLE to start kiosk mode either. Seems like I should just stick with Chrome...

Comment: @user1636349, interesting, it works fine on this end. Does `-private` change anything for you?

Comment: @user1636349, perhaps you can simulate kioks mode with OLE `TheaterMode`, `FullScreen`, `ToolBar`, `StatusBar` properties.