# C#: How can I hide when you start other programs in C# using Win32API?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code:

```
    /********** This code is First way **********/
    String filePath = "ex";
    StratInfo psi = new StartInfo(filePath);
    psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    Process process = Process.Start(psi);
    process.WaitForInputIdle();
    /********************************************/

    /********** This code is Second way **********/
    String filePath = "ex";
    Process process = Process.Start(new StartInfo(filePath));
    process.WaitForInputIdle();

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    private static extern int ShowWindow (int hwnd, int nCmdShow);

    int hWnd = FindWindow(null, "Main Caption");
    if (hWnd != 0) {
        ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);
    }
    /***********************************************/
```

Most of the programs in this way, I solved the problem.

However, some programs have not worked this way.

The first way : not possible at all.

The second way : only a part, and slow. I can hide the main window. But MessageBox is still displayed.

How do I resolve this problem? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the WinExec function, it lets you pass a visibility parameter:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This may give similar results to process, however, it's worth experimenting with.

You mention messageboxes showing - you can't control that, because a program running in your desktop has the ability to do what it wants with the desktop, including popping up random topmost windows.

Try running the program as a service: (this supresses the program's UI):

http://www.howtogeek.com/50786/using-srvstart-to-run-any-application-as-a-windows-service/

Of course, now, when a messagebox is raised by the program, windows doesn't display it, that program is basically 'locked up' there; and you may not also have permissions to run a program as a service.

Why do you want to do this, exactly? You might be suprised at the good workarounds the community suggests.

Good luck anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all GUI elements, you might want to run the process on it's own desktop. Look at this thread for some additional information:

[Creating process to run IE on new Windows desktop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407120/creating-process-to-run-ie-on-new-windows-desktop)

[MSDN: About Window Stations and Desktops](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681928.aspx)

Although you still need to deal with processes that are waiting for user input (dialogs, message boxes, etc.)